# Dynamically allocated string arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I'm trying to understand how dynamically allocated arrays work in C 99. Anyways, I have the following code:

```
int main()
{
    char** members=malloc(4*sizeof(*members));
    *members=malloc(5);
    *members="john";
    *(members+1)="shouldn't work";
    printf("%s \n",*members);
    printf("%s",*(members+1));
    return 0;
}
```

I thought I would get a run time error because I didn't allocate (members+1), but actually it did print both "john" and "shouldn't work", Also, it apperas the the *members=malloc(5) line wasn't necessary. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assignments aren't doing what you think they're doing.  When you assign `*members` or `*(members+1)`, you're assigning the `char*` to each string literal, not copying it to allocated (or not allocated) heap memory.

If instead you replaced your assignments with `strcpy`, i.e.:

```
strcpy(*members, "john");
strcpy(*(members+1), "shouldn't work");
```

Then you will get an access violation on the second assignment but not the first.  Likewise, the reason `malloc(5)` appears to be unnecessary is because you reassign the pointer to point to the string literal, instead of copying the "john" string to the allocated memory.

Comment: The assertion "you will get an access violation on the second assignment" is false: They **may** get an access violation, but the code may just as well work as expected, or lead to some strange, hard to debug behavior later on (including the appearance of some blue elephants as far as the standard is concerned). It is undefined behavior that depends on whatever happens to be stored in `*(members + 1)`, not a deterministic error condition.

Comment: @cmaster Right, the second `strcpy` is technically UB according to the standard, but most modern operating systems will initialize newly `malloc`'d pages to `0` as a security precaution, so dereferencing will force an AV.  If the process had previously `free`d memory, all bets are off.

Answer (score 2):

```
char** members=malloc(4*sizeof(*members));
```

this means you have created an array and allocated memory for four elements that can store the address of a string.

So if you remove the line     *members=malloc(5); then also it will work.

```
int main()
{
char** members=malloc(4*sizeof(*members));
//*members=malloc(5);
*members="john";
*(members+1)="shouldn't work";
printf("%s \n",*members);
printf("%s",*(members+1));
return 0;
}
```

i.e. member can hold four members and each of them can hold the address of a string.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. For your first malloc, `malloc(4*sizeof(*members))`, it would be more clear if you were to use the *type* of the object you're trying to allocate space for, e.g. `malloc(4 * sizeof(char *))` rather than using the name of a variable. **edit:** as cmaster has pointed out, this can cause problems if you change the type of the variable without changing the type in the `malloc()` so take this advice with a grain of salt
2. `*members=malloc(5);` isn't necessary in your case, because your compiler has allocated space for the string `"john"` for you already, and
3. `*members="john";` works by setting the *pointer* at index 0 of your string array to the *address* of the compiler allocated `"john"`
4. Similarly, `*(members+1)="shouldn't work";` actually *does* work because of the point mentioned in 3.
5. Lastly, because of this line -- `*members="john";` -- you have lost the pointer to the memory you `malloc(5)`'ed, so that memory is going to be leaked :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have initialized pointer of type `char**` with `4*sizeof(*members)` I think you are planning to store 4 strings, so recommendation is to allocate memory for all 4 strings, like:

```
char** members=malloc(4*sizeof(*members));
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    members[i] = malloc(100 + 1);  // 100 is a max length of string
              // actually length of each string can be different
```

or you can initialize all pointers with NULL and change them as needed (allocate or point to some allocated memory), e.g.:

```
char** members=malloc(4*sizeof(*members));
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    members[i] = NULL;  
// ... somewhere ....
char str[] = "Some string";
members[2] = str;
// ... somewhere else ....
members[1] = malloc(20);
scanf("%19s", members[1]);
```

And in that case you can check with `if(members[i] != NULL)` to identify items that point data.

Comment: If you have a simple array of `char *` values, then you usually need to know which ones need to be freed and which cannot be freed.  In your example, you would have some non-freeable strings and some freeable ones, which is really a bit messy.  You're making a valid point that there are multiple variants on the theme of `char *`, but it is a good idea to be consistent so that you can free the space reliably.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Sometimes strange questions produce strange answers. This is not unusual :-)